# Pone 4.3 uid and gid not found

Tags: plone

When installing plone 4.3 with the Unified Installer, it says that it isn't finding the gid, even though the group exists.

```
root@adrian:/home/Plone-4.3-UnifiedInstaller# ./install.sh --password=xxx --target=/home/Plone-4.3 --user=admin standalone

Testing /usr/bin/python2.7 for Zope/Plone requirements....
/usr/bin/python2.7 looks OK. We'll try to use it.

Root install method chosen. Will install for use by users:
  ZEO & Client Daemons:      admin
  Code Resources & buildout: plone_buildout

Detailed installation log being written to /home/Plone-4.3-UnifiedInstaller/install.log
Installing Plone 4.3 at /home/Plone-4.3

Using useradd and groupadd to create users and groups.
User 'admin' already exists. No need to create it.
id for admin returned
uid=5006(admin) gid=5007(admin) groups=5007(admin)
Expected to find uid for admin and gid for plone_group but did not.
Please use your system tools to create/edit users and groups, then try again.
```

When I try to do as suggested:

```
root@adrian:/home# groupadd plone_group
groupadd: group 'plone_group' already exists
```

Comment: What does `grep plone /etc/group` say? I suspect the installer might assume that the user you give belongs to the group already if it's not creating it itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installer wants the daemon user to have plone_group for its default group. The pre-existing user you're using already has its own default group.

As a work around, try having the installer create a new daemon user (or let it use plone_daemon).

And, please file this as a bug ticket at http://dev.plone.org. Include details on your operating system and version. Set the component (for the ticket) to "installers". It'll get prompt attention.

Comment: Have added a ticket. https://dev.plone.org/ticket/13545 there was no option for 'component' I could find.

Comment: How do I let it use plone_daemon?

Comment: Just remove "--user=admin" from your install.sh command line. "admin" is, in any case, a bad ID to use for a process.